# how to break a line java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am setting a text of a h4 through java script what i want to do is add new line here's the code

```
$("#description").text("for CCAET and has received significant international scientific recognition. <br /> \n Dr. Armogan has also been responsible for many surgical firsts in retina and cataract management.");
```

now i tried it with multiple solutions but still not working here's another one

```
$("#description").text("or CCAET and has received significant international scientific recognition.Dr. Armogan has also been responsible for many surgical firsts in retina and cataract management."+
                        "abc"+
                         "def");
```

any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `$("#description").html(...)` instead of `$("#description").text(...)`.

Comment: And `<br/>` for a line break

Comment: now working in javascript,it is displaying the <br/> as it is

Comment: @uneebmeer please accept the answer if it is working

Answer (score 3):

Use *html* instead of *text*. This because *html* will render the HTML code. The *text* method will only insert and escape all HTML content. Ref. https://api.jquery.com/html/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var content = "This<br/>is<br/>modified<br/>text";

  $('h4#one').html(content);
  $('h4#two').text(content);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h4 id="one">
  This is initial text
</h4>

<h4 id="two">
  This is initial text
</h4>
```

Answer (score 2):

use the html() function to put the raw html inside an element as

```
$("#description").html("for CCAET and has received significant international scientific recognition. <br /> \n Dr. Armogan has also been responsible for many surgical firsts in retina and cataract management.");
```

Answer (score 2):

use html function with

```
 tag.it will preserve your raw html .
```

`$("#description").html("<pre>for CCAET and has received significant international scientific recognition. <br /> \n Dr. Armogan has also been responsible for many surgical firsts in retina and cataract management.</pre>");`